# Can an even degree galois extension complete p-adically to an even galois extension

Tags: nt.number-theory

Given a galois extension of number fields $L/K$ of even degree, set $n_0=\text{lcm} (\{[L_v:K_v] : v \in M_K \})$ ($L_v$ is any completion corresponding to a place dividing $v$).

Does $2$ divide $n_0$?

This comes up in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61084/examples-of-galois-invariant-central-simple-algebras-which-arent-base-change).

Comment: Is this not a trivial consequence of Cebotarev density?? What am I missing?

Comment: It is! If no one answer had come up I would have deleted the question.

Comment: The question of the title does not agree with the question in the body (the latter is easy if you know Cebotarev density, whereas the former is trivial).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the slightly stronger result is true, that the lcm of orders of Frobenius elements must be even (forget ramified primes, that is). Isn't that a corollary of the Chebotaryov density theorem (there is a Frobenius in every conjugacy class, and some such class contains elements of even order)?

Comment: Why does everyone spell Chebotarev differently?  (Both than me and each other.)

Comment: The sound yo is written ë in Cyrillic, and often therefore just e in Romanised text. Khrushchev is the well known example, so the final syllable is actually sounded shchoff (though there the ch sound swallows the y).